# How can I route to SessionsController#create in my login form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Here's how I have my login form set up:

```
<%= form_tag login_path, method: "post", class: "well form-search" do |f| %>
```

Naturally, this tries to *POST* to the "new" action of my *SessionsController*. I know that `login_path` is evaluated before `method` so I know that this is completely wrong. Just trying to figure out how to make that `login_path` do what I want. I know it is used for both *GET* and *POST*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you created a custom route called `login` that goes to `sessions#new`, but I recommend you add `resources :sessions` to `routes.rb`. That will give you all the routes you need and Rails will send you to the correct action in the controller.

You'd have to update your form to:

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path, class: "well form-search" do |f| %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
<%= form_tag url: { action: "create", controller: 'sessions' }, method: "post", class: "well form-search" do |f| %>
```